# Can i move screens by a button according to a segmented control index in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, button, segmentedcontrol

I would like to have a segmented control and by clicking on GO button according to the segmented index it will take me to English or Spanish version of the app

is it possible?

import Foundation
import UIKit

class SettingsController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var languageSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

@IBAction func goToTest(_ sender: Any) {




}
```

}

Comment: Are you asking wanna to redirect another app when clicking button?didn't get from you

Comment: Do you mean to another app or to use another localization within the same app?

Comment: locally, in the app between 2 screen- let say setting screen and record screen, i want the navigation will be fron a button press with the info; selected in the segment contol

Answer (score 0):

[Apple's documentation on UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol) is probably a good place to start. You'll see that there's a property called [selectedSegmentIndex](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol/1618575-selectedsegmentindex).

You can use this in your button tap event action to act on the selected index, for example:

```
if languageSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
    // Navigate for second item
} else {
    // Navigate for first/default item
}
```

If you plan on more options you may want to consider using a switch statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

**I used a singleton in order to choose the language**

---

@IBAction func segmentdControlLanguage(_ sender: Any) {
        switch selectedSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            LanguageMananger.getInstance().setUserDef(lan: Constant.LanguageSet.English.rawValue)
            print("setting-English mode")

```
    case 1:
        LanguageMananger.getInstance().setUserDef(lan: Constant.LanguageSet.Hebrew.rawValue)
        print("setting-Hebrew mode")

    default:
        print("no lanague was choosen")
    }
}
```